# Возможно ли повысить размер загружаемых изображений с текущих 2Мб?

Tags: предложение, нытьё

Периодически требуется в вопрос/ответ поместить `*.gif` изображение с демонстрацией работы программы. Проблема в том, что максимальный размер - **2Мб**, а это, при чуть высшем, чем минимальном, качестве 3 (редко 4) секунды видео, преобразованного в `*.gif`. Я от этого страдаю, засим в вопросе будет метка [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91).

**Собственно вопрос:**

Сколь долго мы вынуждены будем мириться с этим ограничением и стоит ли надеяться на изменения в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инлайн изображений работает и для вручную вписаных ссылок.

Т.е. закачать 2-х метровую гифку нельзя, а вот вставить прямо в пост 40-мегабайтный гиф с imgur - можно. Попробуйте создать пост со следующим содержимым, и посмотрите на preview:

```
![add][1]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/A61SaA1.gif
```

Comment: Чьорт возьми, таки работает) Спасибо! Ждите много многометровых гифок в вопросах/ответах)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Учтите, что такие картинки будут преобразованы в ссылки, а если я на них наткнусь. Если файл больше двух метров, то правило хорошего тона — сделать маленькую превьюшку со ссылкой на полноценный файл.

Comment: @Discord, обещаю не злоупотреблять) И кстати, на англо-саксонской мете читал вчера, что вроде можно перед точкой перед расширением картинки в ссылке на неё ставить разные буквы и получятся картинки разного качества... Надо будет поэкспериментировать)

Comment: Вот пост с англ. меты про ресайз изображений: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/3212712. Одна проблема - работает только (как я понял) для картинок, загруженных чрез SO, т.е. с тем же ограничение на 2Мб.

Answer (score 7):

Только не это!

1. GIF не предназначен для видео. Это костыль родом из девяностых, пора уже прекращать издевательство над форматом. Он тормозной, неэффективный, ресурсоёмкий. Просто хватит.
2. Не у всех резиновый доступ в интернет. Сайт смотрят и с мобилок, где траффик для многих имеет значение. Не надо издеваться над пользователями десятиметровыми гифками, которые нельзя не скачать при просмотре странички. Просто хватит.

Хотите выложить **видео** — выкладывайте **видео**. Для этого есть YouTube. Только извольте всё равно сделать вопрос самодостаточным. Если для вы не можете объяснить проблему без десятиминутного видео на сотни мегабайт, то вы плохо поработали с проблемой. И я не буду напоминать, что желающих смотреть ваши видео желающих много не найдётся, если только вы не будете предлагать по 500 репы за просмотр через баунти.

Comment: а как насчет webm?

Comment: @PashaPash Я не в курсе, какие форматы в каких браузерах поддерживаются, но если это достаточно кроссплатформенно, но почему бы и нет. Правда есть проблема: начнут же видео ещё и со звуком добавлять...

Comment: Gif мне нравится тем, что прямо в вопросе/ответе можно посмотреть видео без перехода по ссылкам, внезависимости от ресурсоёмкости и прочих неэффективностей. Это просто удобно, ИМХО. А ограничивать использование картинок для экономии трафика... Это не выход, по моему. Этак можно и сайт начать упрощать... CSS все вырезать, их ведь подгрузка тоже трафик ест) И мне обычно надо не более 5 секунд видео и для его показа неохота людей по ссылкам на всякие youtub-ы гонять...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Если для пяти секунд вам не хватает 2 метров, то вы что-то делаете не так. / Вообще-то воспроизведение видео безо всяких плагинов поддерживается всеми браузерами, то есть то, что вы можете вставить видео как картинку, но не как видео — это ограничения движка сайта, а не технические. По-хорошему надо не увеличивать ограничения на img, а позволить вставлять video с некоторыми ограничениями. Вот за это я готов проголосовать. Только об этом разумнее писать на MSE, а не здесь.

Comment: @Discord, ну... Я силами AndroidStudio записываю видео с телефона и потом онлайн-конвертером перевожу в гиф... Качество видео беру на 1 выше минимального, снимаю 4 секунды и получаю файл в 2.3Мб. Печаль. На счёт вставки видео - вот мне лично почему-то ближе именно гифки, а не видео) Но будь такая возможность - я был бы рад, конечно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Воспользуйтесь оптимизаторами, вырежьте ненужное.

Comment: @Discord, ну, это ж сколько гуглить надо... Думать ещё... Проще на мете вопрос с меткой "нытьё" создать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я всего лишь объясняю, как избавиться от меня, так как большие гифки я буду превращать в ссылки.

Comment: @Discord, я понял вашу позицию и постараюсь её учитывать)

Comment: @Discord, о, на imgur-e получилось обрезать загруженную гифку и она стала меньше 2Мб) Но всё равно неудобно - много лишних действий(